# Line skip in fontsize not working on the last paragraph

Tags: luatex, fontsize

The space between lines in `\fontsize{size}{skip}` is not working correctly. The last paragraph does not have the line skip set as it should. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

%   \begingroup
    \fontsize{6}{8}\selectfont
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \normalsize
%   \endgroup

    \lipsum[6-7]
\end{document}
```

As it can be seen in the picture, the `lipsum[1]` is printed in normal size, the first four paragraphs of `lipsum[1-5]` are printed in smaller size correctly, but the last paragraph of `lipsum[1-5]` has the line skip different from the others.

[image: different sizes and spaces]

How can I correctly set the line skip to all paragraphs in the range inside `\fontsize{6}{8}\selectfont` to `\normalsize`? I'm compiling my document with `LuaLaTeX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're changing the line spacing in the final paragraph when you do the `\normalsize`. Try putting a blank line before `\normalsize` and see what happens.

Comment: It fixed it. Is there a reason why must be a blank line for it to work?

Comment: You get one line spacing per paragraph and that will be whatever the value is set to at the end of the paragraph. By not having the blank line there, you're changing the line spacing to the spacing corresponding to `\normalsize` for that last paragraph.